# Invalid data type

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

The following code is invalid:

```
data A = Int | [Int] | (Int, Int)
```

Why is it ok to use the concrete type `Int` as part of a data type definition, but not the concrete type `[Int]` or `(Int, Int)`?

Comment: It does not use the first type as an `Int`, it sees `Int` here as a constructor.

Comment: Haskell's unions are [tagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why is it ok to use the concrete type Int as part of a data type definition (..)

It is **not OK**.

What you here have written is the definition of a data type `A` that has a **constructor named `Int`**. This has nothing to do with the data type `Int`, it is simply a coincidence that the name of the constructor is the same as the name of a type, but that is not a problem for the Haskell compiler, since Haskell has a clear distinction between types and constructor names.

You can not use `[Int]` however, since `[Int]` is not an identifier (it starts with an open square bracket), nor is it an operator (that can only use symbols). So Haskell does not really knows how to deal with this and errors on this input.

If you want to define a datatype that can take an `Int` value, you need to **add it as a parameter**. You can also define constructors for your `[Int]` and `(Int, Int)` parameters. For instance:

```
data A = Int Int | Ints [Int] | Int2 (Int,Int)
```

So here there are three constructors: `Int`, `Ints`, and `Int2`. And the first constructor takes an `Int` as parameter, the second one an `[Int]`, and the last one an `(Int, Int)`.

That being said, this will probably result into a lot of confusion, so it is better to use constructor names that cause less confusion, for instance:

```
data A = A Int | As [Int] | A2 (Int,Int)
```

Note that the `A` of `data A` can be used in the signature of the functions, whereas the constructors (in boldcase) are used as values (so in the implementation of the function, that is the pattern matching in the head of the clauses, and in order to construct a value in the body of the clauses).

Comment: It might help to call out that the capitalized things in bold only exist at the term-level (in code), while the other capitalized things only appear at the type level (in type signatures). I think the syntax can be confusing in this respect.

Comment: `A1 Int` would cause even less confusion.